# Неправильная конвертация lat/long в UTM

Tags: c++, qt

Имею вот такие координаты в latitude и longitude

```
latitude_wgs84_radians: 0.924593
longitude_wgs84_radians: 0.176054
```

С помощью `GeographicLib` пытаюсь перевести их в `UTM` выходит у меня значение

```
latitude: 185532
longitude: 102251
```

что неправильно, ибо координаты указаны в `radians`, а не в градусах.
Вот мой код

```
double lat = latitude_wgs84_radians, lon = longitude_wgs84_radians;
int zone = -2;
bool northp;
double x, y;
UTMUPS::Forward(lat, lon, zone, northp, x, y);
std::string zonestr = UTMUPS::EncodeZone(zone, northp);
std::cout << fixed << std::setprecision(0)
          << zonestr << " " << x << " " << y << "\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так и в чем проблема перевести координаты в градусы?

```
double lat = latitude_wgs84_radians * 180 / M_PI;
double lon = longitude_wgs84_radians * 180 / M_PI;
int zone = -2;
bool northp;
double x, y;
UTMUPS::Forward(lat, lon, zone, northp, x, y);
```

Константа `M_PI` определена в `math.h`

Comment: `latitude: 568000
longitud: 5.866e+06` второе значение какое-то не нормальное.

Comment: @Insider Какую Вы библиотеку используете? Вот здесь https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/classGeographicLib_1_1UTMUPS.html#a921d6c23e728e0b17651902d43fb56e8 у функции совершенно другие аргументы

Comment: В самом начале код. lat и long я получаю из симулятора, остальное как и в примере.

Comment: @Insider Вы предыдущий вопрос видели? Какую библиотеку Вы используете?

Comment: Я ведь писал в вопросе - GeographicLib

Comment: @Insider перейдите по моей ссылке и посмотрите что функция `UTMUPS::Forward` принимает не 6 параметров как у Вас, а 10. Два последних необязательніе

Comment: тогда бы компилятор выдавал как минимум ошибку и я знаю что написано на том сайте, пролистайте его на самый верх и увидите другой пример, где принимаются 6 параметров в тот же Forward.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68760/discussion-between-insider-and-anton-shchyrov).

Comment: @Insider Второе значение вполне нормальное `5.866e+06` = `5866000`. Это называется [Экспоненциальная запись.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Comment: @zed как это переделать в `5866000`? И еще вопрос, как их переделать в такое писание? `53.026606 10.180206`

Comment: @Insider 1. По ссылке на вики, что я дал, сходить лень? `5.866e+06` = `5.866 * pow(10, 06)` = `5.866 * 1000000` = `5866000`. 2. Это координаты в метрах. Если вы хотите из этих координат в метрах (x, y) получить координаты в градусах (lon, lat), вам надо воспользоваться функцией `UTMUPS::Reverse`.